# Math.round() mostra o resultado 1675, mas eu queria que ele arredondasse para 1700

Tags: javascript, random

Estou com problemas com o `Math.round()` no JavaScript, ele mostra o resultado `1675`, mas eu queria que ele arredondasse para `1700`.

```js
var altura = 170
var peso = 70
var idade = 30
var tmb 

tmb = 66.5 + (13.75 * peso) + (5.0 * altura) - (6.8 * idade)

console.log(Math.round(tmb))
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Como aparentemente você quer arredondar 2 dígitos na parte inteira então tem que fazer esses dígitos virarem decimais, dividindo por 100 e depois voltar para o normal multiplicando por 100, ou seja, pura matemática.

```js
var altura = 170
var peso = 70
var idade = 30
var tmb = 66.5 + (13.75 * peso) + (5.0 * altura) - (6.8 * idade)
console.log(Math.round(tmb / 100) * 100)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/Round.js).